# How to change the value set in useContext in another test?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Good afternoon, first of all, thank you for your attention.

I created a test for a file that has a store dependency that uses useContext.

To be able to test this file, I added the store as follows:

```js
jest.mock('react', () => {
  const ActualReact = jest.requireActual('react');
  return {
    ...ActualReact,
    useContext: () => {
      return {
        form: {
           email: {
             id: 'name',
             name: 'nameTeste',
             value: 'teste',
          },
        },
      };
    },
  };
});
```

In the next test I would like to change the default value to another value, e.g.

```js
it('should return field required', () => {
 
  jest.mock('react', () => {
    const ActualReact = jest.requireActual('react');
      return {
        ...ActualReact,
        useContext: () => {
          return {
            form: {
              email: {
                id: 'email',
                name: 'email',
                value: 'teste@teste.com',
             },
           },
         };
       },
     };
   });
    validateField('teste@teste.com', 'email');
    expect(mock.setErrorForm).toHaveBeenCalledWith('email', 'Este campo es requerido.');
  });
```

How can I change the predefined value?